# NSTreeController add and addChild methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, addition, nstreecontroller

GOTO UPDATE

I have a `NSTreeController` controller that binded (`Content Object`) to content (`NSTreeNode *`) of my application delegate. Also I have `NSOutlineView` in my window that binded to my controller.

Everything works fine, the content is displayed in outline view, but I can not `add` (`addChild`, `insert` etc) any items though controller methods and `canAdd` (`canAddChild` etc) methods of controller always return `NO` (I have a buttons which "enabled" is binded to controller and this buttons are disabled).

Where is my mistake?

UPDATE

I want to give some more information about my situation.

I have a MyNode class:

```
@interface MyNode : NSTreeNode {
    NSString* title;
}

@property (retain) NSString* title;


@end
```

I also have the NSTreeController object in my nib file. The `childrenKeyPath` is set to `childNodes` in IB and the `countKeyPath` and `isLeafKeyPath` are empty.

The controller mode is set to `Class` and Class name is `MyNode`.

The **Content Object** (not Content Array) is binded to `MyDocument`s `rootNode` property:

```
@property (readonly) MyNode* rootNode;

...

rootNode = [[MyNode alloc] init];
rootNode.title = @"Root";

MyNode *childNode = [[MyNode alloc] init];
childNode.title = @"Child";

[[rootNode mutableChildNodes] addObject:childNode];
```

And I have NSOulineView in my window which `content` is binded to TreeController's `arrangedObjects`. The content is displayed. I even can edit the title of my nodes, but I can not add or insert any (child) nodes through my TreeController.

I have 2 buttons: "Add Child" and "Insert Child" connected to the `addChild` and `insertChild` actions of TreeController and enabled is binded to `canAddChild` and `canInsertChild` properties of TreeController. The buttons are disabled.. and I cannot add or insert any child nodes.

Where is mistake?

UPDATE 2

I have some good news =)

I changed my Document class like this:

```
@interface MyDocument : NSDocument {
    NSMutableArray *rootNodes;
    MyNode* rootNode;
}

@property (readonly) NSArray* rootNodes;

..

rootNodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

rootNode = [[MyNode alloc] init];
rootNode.title = @"Root";

MyNode* childNode = [[MyNode alloc] init];
childNode.title = @"Child";

[[rootNode mutableChildNodes] addObject:childNode];

[rootNodes addObject:rootNode];
```

And binded **Content Array** (not Content Object) to `MyDocument.rootNodes` property and everything works fine.

Why doesn't the addXXX methods work with single object? I can not find anything about it in documentation...

And why can TreeController add root elements to the `rootNodes`? `rootNodes` is the `NSArray`, not the `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: How are you setting up the `NSTreeNode` instances? What are their `representedObject`s?

Comment: `content = [[NSTreeNode alloc] init];` and they have no represented object.

Comment: What content does your NSOutlineView display, then?

Comment: Just empty cells but the structure is ok. I've also made a subclass of NSTreeNoge with the `title` property and bind the outline view column to it — the displaying is ok, but add and insert methods does not work

Comment: I think your problem is that the nodes need to support inserts and updates for this to work. I'm completely baffled, though. You say the structure is ok, so you must be instantiating a bunch of `NSTreeNode`s. How do you assign child nodes to their parent? Would you post the relevant code from the app delegate?

Comment: I insert the child elements using `mutableChildNodes` array of NSTreeNode: `[[content mutableChildNodes] addObject: newNode]`. What interface should the tree node support? There is nothing about it in documentation.

Comment: I was disappointed by the docs on NSTreeController, too. Sounds like what you're doing is fine. And now I know how to use `NSTreeNode` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it! Try setting `childrenKeyPath` to `mutableChildNodes`.

Comment: It doesn't work too.. see my UPDATE 2. While I use Content Array instead of Content object I have an exception for `mutableChildNodes`.

Comment: So, the correct fix is: (1) use the Content Array binding instead of the Content Object binding and (2) provide an array of root nodes instead of a single root node -- is that right?

Comment: I don't understand "rootNodes is the NSArray, not the NSMutableArray."

Comment: 1. No, my "UPDATE2" is not a correct fix. The documentation said that " The root content object of the tree can be a single object, or an array of objects", but `add:` and `insert:` methods doesn't work with single object. I can't understand why.
2. Sorry for my English =) `rootNodes` is a property of type `NSArray`. `NSArray` has no methods like `addObject:`. How can TreeController insert elements through this property?

Comment: No problem. Neither the property declaration nor the instance variable declaration matters when determining the selectors to which your `rootNodes` instance can respond. The tree controller simply asks it whether it can respond to e.g. `addObject:`, and it says yes. The compiler uses the type system to check the selector names and parameter types, and Xcode uses it for property completion, but nothing in Obj-C prevents code from using any selector an instance defines.

Comment: I understand that the behavior you're seeing doesn't match the documentation. I agree NSTreeController seems poorly documented.

Answer (score -1):

You should not add nodes by writing

```
[rootNodes addObject:rootNode];
```

Instead you should have this in File's Owner of your  XIB/NIB file (MyDocument class):

```
IBOutlet NSTreeController* treeController;
```

And connect this Outlet in IB with your Tree Controller. Then just write:

```
//[rootNodes addObject:rootNode];
  [treeController addObject:rootNode];
```

By doing so, you also can get rid of rootNodes init:

```
//rootNodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Also, to add child nodes, you can use

```
[treeController addChild:childNode];
```

This will add a childNode to the currently selected node.